# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration with webpack compilation error

Tags: npm, webpack, cypress

While running cypress tests getting error:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:UsersCypressode_modulescypress-cucumberpreprocessorlibesolveStepDefinition' in 'C:\Users\Cypress\cypress\integration\features'
resolve 'C:UsersCypressode_modulescypress-cucumber-preprocessorlibesolveStepDefinition' in 'C:\Users\Cypress\cypress\integration\features'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Users\CypressProject\package.json (relative path: ./cypress/integration/features)
```

My webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  node: { fs: "empty", child_process: "empty", readline: "empty" },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.feature$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My plugins index.js file

```
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)

/** 
 * Used to setup TypeScript support in cypress 
 */
const wp = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor')
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

function getConfigurationByFile (file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('./cypress/', 'config', `${file}.json`)
  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile)
}

module.exports = (on,config) => {
    const file = process.env.ENV_FILE//config.env.envFile
  const options = {     
    webpackOptions: require("../webpack.config.js")
  };
  on('file:preprocessor', wp(options))
  if(file==null){
  return getConfigurationByFile('local');
  }
  else{
    return getConfigurationByFile(file);
  }
}
```

I observed \ , \n , \r missing from the path(1st line of error), due to this only everything is failing I guess. I cleared all the cache but no luck.
Anyone has idea regarding this. Thanks in advance.